# Java: How should I differentiate the Save button from Save As button?

Tags: java

I am trying to write code for the `Save` and `Save As` menuItems in my javafx Application.

I have already written my `Save As` menuItem.

```
menuItemSaveAs.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>(){
     // run the saveAs(); method     
     @Override
     public void handle(final ActionEvent e){
          saveAs();
     }
})
```

However, when it comes to writing the `Save` menuItem, I need to check **if the current workflow is associated with a file already**, if it is, then just save current workflow to the current file. Otherwise, perform the `saveAs()`, whereby the save dialogue is displayed and user has to type in the file name and then save. I have code written for `saveAs()` already.

It is the checking **if the current workflow is associated with a file already** part that I do not feel confident.

At the moment, my naive way of checking is:

```
public void save(){
     if(file != null){    // <-  not sure if this is the right check. 
          // write objects to file
     } else{
          saveAs();
     }
}
```

Since I have other menuItems `New`, `Save`, `Save As` , `Open`  and `Close` in my application. Using this approach, I have to make sure `FileInputStream` and `FileOutputStream` are never `close` in the first 4 menuItems, i.e.  `New`, `Save`, `Save As` , `Open`. And they can only be closed if the `Close` menuItem is clicked.
Is this the correct approach?

Are there any other better ways to handle this ?

Answer (score 0):

mynameisJEFF, Your approach is correct. After you picked the file using save as, remaining operations is common for both save and save as.